# JAVA: Modify, Delete, List an arraylist addressbook

Tags: java, arraylist

Be kind, i am learning.

I am creating a addressbook and I need the added names to go into an arraylist.  The problem I am having is with modifying, deleting and listing all in arraylist.  How do I go about this?

Here is my class file:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class AddressBook {

    private static int totalNumber;

    public static int getTotal() {

        //Returns total number of employees
        return totalNumber;
    }

    private Date lastModified;
    private String fullname;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zip;
    private String phone;


    public AddressBook() {
        super();
    }

    /*public AddressBook(Date lastModified, String fullname, String address, String city, String state, String zip, String phone, int month, int day, int year) { 
        this.fullname = fullname;
        this.address = address;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.zip = zip;
        this.phone = phone; 
        GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month-1, day );
        this.lastModified = calendar.getTime();

    }*/
    public AddressBook(String fullname, String address, String city, String state, String zip, String phone) { 
        this.fullname = fullname;
        this.address = address;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.zip = zip;
        this.phone = phone; 


    }


    public Date getLastModified() {

        return lastModified;
    }

    public void setLastModified(int month, int day, int year) {
        month = 00; 
        day = 00;
        year = 0000;
        return;
    }
    public String getFullname() {
        return fullname;
    }
    public void setFullname(String fullname) {
        this.fullname = fullname;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
    public String getZip() {
        return zip;
    }
    public void setZip(String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [name=" + this.fullname + ", Address=" + this.address + ", City="
                + this.city + ", state=" + this.state + ", zip=" + this.zip
                + ", phone=" + this.phone + "]";
    }



}
```

Here is the test file:

```
import java.util.*;

public class testAddressBook {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        boolean switcher = true;
        do {
        System.out.println("\n\tAddress Book Menu");
        System.out.println("\n\t\tEnter A to (A)dd Person ");
        System.out.println("\t\tEnter D to (D)elete Person");
        System.out.println("\t\tEnter M to (M)odify Person");
        System.out.println("\t\tEnter S to (S)earch Address Book ");
        System.out.println("\t\tEnter L to (L)ist ALL (sorted) ");
        System.out.println("\t\tEnter Q to Quit");
        System.out.print("\n\tPlease enter your choice: ");
        char choice = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0);


        while ((choice != 'A') && (choice != 'D') && (choice != 'M')  && (choice != 'S') && (choice != 'L')&& (choice != 'Q')) {
            System.out.println("Invalid choice!  Please select (A)dd, (D)elete, (M)odify, (S)earch, (L)ist or (Q)uit: ");
            choice = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
        }


        AddressBook newPerson = new AddressBook();
        ArrayList<AddressBook> person = new ArrayList<>(); 

        switch (choice) {
        case 'A' :      
        System.out.println("\nTo add a person, follow the prompts.");

        System.out.print("\nEnter Fullname: ");
        newPerson.setFullname(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Enter Address: ");
        newPerson.setAddress(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Enter City: ");
        newPerson.setCity(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Enter State: ");
        newPerson.setState(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Enter Zip: ");
        newPerson.setZip(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Enter Phone Number: ");
        newPerson.setPhone(sc.nextLine());



        person.add(new AddressBook(newPerson.getFullname(), newPerson.getAddress(), newPerson.getCity(), newPerson.getState(), newPerson.getZip(), newPerson.getPhone()));
        System.out.println(person.get(0));


        System.out.println("\nYou have successfully added a new person!");

        break;

        case 'D' :



        break;
        case 'M' :



            break;
        case 'S' :




            break;
        case 'L' :








                                break;
        case 'Q' :
            switcher = false;
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        default:

        }

    }
        while (switcher != false);

    }}
```

Comment: "The problem I am having is with modifying....." What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) java doc.

Here is some information on the [for-loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Look at.

`get()`

`add()`

`remove()`

`person.get(0)` is the actually your AddressBook object. You will be able to modify that entry using that

Hope this gives enough hints to get you started.

**Beginner tip:** Just remember to keep your steps small. Once you are able to create a single entry, modify, then delete it. Do it for two. Notice the duplicate code... and then program it with the loop

**Some errors in what you have so far:**

```
    AddressBook newPerson = new AddressBook();
    ArrayList<AddressBook> person = new ArrayList<>(); 
    // ... adding values to your newPerson
    person.add(new AddressBook(newPerson.getFullname(),           newPerson.getAddress(), newPerson.getCity(), newPerson.getState(), newPerson.getZip(), newPerson.getPhone()));
```

You are populating your person. Then creating a new person with the same values of the populated person. You could simply pass your original person into the arraylist

```
    person.add(newPerson);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple **suggestions** for you:

1. Use meaningful names. For example `ArrayList<AddressBook>` should have been named `listOfAddressBook` etc.
2. You can directly add the `AddressBook` object to list: I mean:
   `person.add(newPerson)` and not `person.add(new AddressBook(newPerson.getFullname(), newPerson.getAddress(), newPerson.getCity(), newPerson.getState(), newPerson.getZip(), newPerson.getPhone()));` And again there is a confusion that object is of type `AddressBook` but name is `newPerson`.
3. There are methods to remove an item or modify an item in [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and it is better to read about them to improve your learning rather than asking for help. I encourage you to read about them in JLS.
4. Also you can declare your list as:
   `List<AddressBook> person = new ArrayList<>();` so go and find out why this ie better than your approach.